# Android webview image quality loss before 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, image, android-4.4-kitkat, loss, rescale

I have a website running a few images using the swipe js I found on github.

I created a WebView to load that webpage however I am running into severe image quality loss on versions before 4.4 kitkat.

I have tried the solution offered
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/gingerbread-release/WebCore/platform/graphics/android/ImageSourceAndroid.cpp

However page returns blank.

Any help?

Comment: Are you able to show your code? Or a logfile?

Comment: Its's okay I figured out. It seems I had to split and reduce the image size to 400px each and put it together... in height:"wrap_content." width:"fill_parent"...